# Check if user is inactive (last time he logged in) node.js mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a little question. I would like to check when a user was logged in the last time. If the account is inactive it will be deleted from the database. I have no clue how to implement this. or how to check the time the user has logged in the last time.
Can someone help me, please... I would be very happy if someone could help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question It is not clear what exactly you want but whatever I understand you can do below things

**Last Login time** :

1. add a datetime field in database table which will hold time whenever
   user login.
2. On login whenever user login just set current
   timestamp in the lastlogin table field

Comment: First of all , thanks for your help ;). 
So you mean when a user login in i should somehow add a timestamp and than i have to check all timestamps. so i can get the oldest ones?

Comment: @darkspuggeti no only 1 timestamp is enough. you just need to update it on user login. as name denoes you have to store last login time so just update one field only

Comment: ohhh yea i got it. I will try it now.. Thanks bro